# javascript onmousedown and updating the location of an object

Tags: javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
    #container { 
    width: 320px; 
    height: 480px;
    border: 1px solid red;

    }
</style>

</head>
<body>


<div style="position: relative;" id="container">
 <canvas id="myCanvas" width="320" height="480" 
   style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; z-index: 0;"></canvas>
    <canvas id="plane" width="320" height="480" 
   style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; z-index: 0;"></canvas>

 <canvas id="canvas2" width="100" height="100" 
   style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; z-index: 1;"></canvas>
</div>



<script>
var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var c2=document.getElementById("canvas2");
var c3=document.getElementById("plane");

var plane;
var ground;
var score1 = "1"
var score = score1;
var increase = 6;
var delay = 40;
var scorez;
var fall = 0;


start();

function start(){
    backgrounds();
    var scorez = setInterval(scoring, delay);
    setInterval(planeUpdate, delay);
    setInterval(donwer, delay);

}


function backgrounds(){
    var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
    var my_gradient=ctx.createLinearGradient(0,0,0, 280);
    my_gradient.addColorStop(0,"white");
    my_gradient.addColorStop(1,"blue");
    ctx.fillStyle=my_gradient;
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,320,480);

    ground = c.getContext("2d");
    ctx.fillStyle="black";
    ctx.fillRect(0,450 , 320 ,30);

}

function scoring(){
    scores();
    score2();

}
function scores(){
    score -= 3-(3+increase);
}
function score2(){
    var context = c2.getContext('2d');
    context.clearRect(0, 0, c2.width, c2.height);
    var w = c2.width;
    c2.width = 1;
    c2.width = w;

    var text=c2.getContext("2d");
    text.font="20px Georgia";
    text.fillText(score ,15,20);
    var text=c2.getContext("2d");
    text.font="20px Georgia";
    text.fillText(fall ,40,40);


}


function hit(){

}

function loes(){
    clearInterval(scorez);

}


    plane = c3.getContext('2d');
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = "images/Plane.png"; //transparent png


function planeUpdate(){
    var context = c3.getContext('2d');
    context.clearRect(0, 0, c3.width, c3.height);
    var w = c3.width;
    c3.width = 1;
    c3.width = w;

        plane.drawImage(img, 40, fall, 50, 50);


}
function donwer(){
    //myCanvas.onmousedown = function(e){
        fall -= 1-2;
    //}
}

</script> 
<!--
http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-BrJHwoqM2qg/Uq94Il8t-1I/AAAAAAAAD7s/vyFLZUgMkdA/s1600/Plane.png

--!>
</body>
</html>
```

So my issue is; is that I can not seem to get onmousedown function to work. Could somebody please suggest what I am doing wrong. Thank you. I would like the plan to move down when the mouse is not pressed and while the mouse is being held the plan to go up. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`myCanvas` is undefined.

You already stored a reference to `canvas#myCanvas` with `var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");`, so use `c` instead of `myCanvas`:

```
c.onmousedown = function(e){
    fall -= 1-2;
}
```

Or you could use `document.getElementById("myCanvas").onmousedown = ...`